# Will "Harry Potter and the Cursed Child" be available in any form other than a play?

Tags: harry-potter, the-cursed-child

As a Harry Potter fan who won't be able to make it to London, I was wondering if what J.K. Rowling has called "the eighth part" of the Harry Potter series would be available to those of us outside of the UK. Any information from interviews, J.K. Rowling's twitter account, or any other credible source would be appreciated, but please don't answer based on speculation.

[image: Advertisement for Harry Potter and the Cursed Child, Parts I & II]

Comment: I spent quite a lot on tickets for this, so I (selfishly) hope that it remains a play only for a long time. I want exclusivity, damn it!

Comment: Let's be honest they won't sacrifice the world wide market of HP eventually the play will be released onto blu-ray and DVD. (As in a high quality recording of the play, probably performed without an audience). Money, Money, Money.

Comment: And *Tales of Beedle the Bard* won't be available either other than the seven handwritten charity copies.

Comment: @DrRDizzle £130 each for three tickets made me wince a bit when I bought them, but there was no way I was going to miss this. Wasn't overly happy about the way the priority booking was handled, though! There was quite a lot of swearing involved when I finally got my e-mail almost an hour late and there were just under 16,000 people in the queue ahead of me.

Comment: @b_jonas Yes, but this is "the eighth chapter" of Harry's tale, while *Beedle the Bard* is insignificant to the story. You must see the difference between the two!

Comment: @LordVoldemort I'm pretty sure b_jonas was joking to make a point; [*The Tales of Beedle the Bard* was released to the public](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tales_of_Beedle_the_Bard#Public_editions) a year after the charity auction, ostensibly after [public outcry over the exclusivity](https://web.archive.org/web/20080809074342/http://www.scholastic.com/aboutscholastic/news/press_07302008_CP.htm)

Comment: @LordVoldemort - I gotta say, *Tales of Beedle the Bard* felt a lot more like a Harry Potter book. (I guess it all depends on the author.)

Comment: You are able to purchase tickets on a Friday at midday or 1pm, I've forgotten which time now via the link at the bottom of the page called "The Friday 40" where 40 tickets are released for sale. You're put into a queue for 2 pages before you can look through the available options on tickets. Hope you have fun :) I was mind blown seeing this production and would love to see it again!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### The script will be published in Book form

The rehearsal edition of the script was released as a book on July 31st, 2016.

> Print and digital editions will publish simultaneously after the play’s world premiere this summer, and will comprise of the version of the play script at the time of the play’s preview performances.
>   ...
>   Special Rehearsal Edition of the script book will later be replaced by a Definitive Collector’s Edition.
>   <sub>([source](https://www.pottermore.com/news/ww-publishing-cursed-child-script-book-announcement))</sub>

A later edition featuring the final script will be released as a paperback on July 25th, 2017.

> This revised paperback edition updates the "special rehearsal edition" with the conclusive and final dialogue from the play, which has subtly changed since its rehearsals, as well as a conversation piece between director John Tiffany and writer Jack Thorne, who share stories and insights about reading playscripts. This edition also includes useful background information including the Potter family tree and a timeline of events from the wizarding world prior to the beginning of Harry Potter and the Cursed Child.
>   <sub>([source](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/133821666X))</sub>

Comment: Keep in mind, it's still the script, so it will read like a play, not a novel.

Comment: @TaylorAllred - Keep in mind, it's still written by Jack Thorne, so it will read like fanfiction, not a Harry Potter book.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I heard from a friend who is reading it.

Answer (score 14):

It has been announced that copies of the play script(s) will be released, the first one being the day after the play's premiere. See [ibid](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/55866/ibid)'s [answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/118030/5833) for the full information.

---

As far as I'm aware, there has been no mention of official plans to release the material in any form other than a play. The best I could find is that there will be a summary made available "at a later date":

> ### Do I have to see both parts?
>
> Part One will only be half the story, so the experience would be incomplete without seeing how the story ends. Likewise, if you only see Part Two you may find it hard to follow the story. We do recommend that you try to see both parts consecutively, but if you are only able to commit to one part in the first booking period, there will be a Thursday evening performance of Part One and a Friday evening performance of Part Two. On these days, tickets to each part can be bought together or separately.
>
> For performances from 21 September 2016, Wednesday matinee and Wednesday evening performances of Part One and Part Two can also be bought together or separately. Details of when Saturday and Sunday performances of Part One and Part Two can be bought separately will be announced at a later date.
>
> **We will provide a summary of Part One and/or Part Two at a later date for those who are unable to commit to seeing both parts.**
>
> <sub>[Your Questions Answered | Harry Potter And The Cursed Child](http://www.harrypottertheplay.com/questions/)</sub>

And, as mentioned in the comments, it's likely there will be other opportunities to see the material (DVD/Blu-Ray releases of recordings, for example) even if you can't go to see it in London.

Comment: And hopefully, they'll license the scripts so that every local community theater can start up their own production. :)

Comment: @SeanDuggan: That will come, but they'll milk the London and Broadway stages, and follow that with travelling shows first. (Sorry, but I've become rather cynical about these sorts of things.)

Comment: I'm sure some form of book will appear eventually.

Comment: @ThruGog It's being published this July. See [my answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/118030/55866).

Comment: @Ibid Not what I expected - but great!

Comment: @ThruGog would be greater if we got Rowling's version.

Comment: @ibid Not sure what you mean by "Rowling's version"? As far as I know she helped write the script for the play.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist It's written by Jack Thorne, based off of "an original story by J K Rowling". Rowling was also a co-producer.