# Will there be a Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them novelization?

Tags: harry-potter, novel, jk-rowling, fantastic-beasts

Warner Bros is making a *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them* film with a script from JK Rowling.

Is there any official word from Rowling or any of the producers at Warner Bros if she or anyone else will or will not be writing a novelization of the upcoming film?

The novelization can either be one set in the movie universe (like most novelizations) or one set in the book universe (like most of Rowling's [other Harry Potter writings](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/114611/55866)), but follows a similar story as the movie. (The second option is more probable if Rowling is writing it.)

### Are there any plans for a novelization?

(The current book obviously doesn't count.)

Comment: Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/106660/55866

Comment: [TV Tropes: Recursive Adaption](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RecursiveAdaptation)

Comment: I have just acquired a copy of the screenplay. Not that it's any use to me since I'm not seeing the movie until next week :-(

Comment: @Valorum - I got my copy Thursday night. Still haven't seen the movie, but from what I've heard, the filmmakers added the usual bunch of nonsense that was never in Rowling's writing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### No

> **Screenplay - Fantastic! The movie- fabulous! However, when do we get a new novel? I happen to love the magic of your words. Pls?**
>
> **J.K. Rowling**: *I'm working on it (literally). And thank you!*
>
> **CONFIRMED, GUYS! THERE WILL BE A NEWT SCAMANDER NOVELS!**
>
> **J.K. Rowling**: *No, no, no. There won't be Newt Scamander novels. Only movies. Calm down, there!*
>
> ([Twitter](https://twitter.com/jk_rowling/status/811577670463004680))

What we got instead is the screenplay, published in book form, ala Cursed Child. Only this time it's actually being written by Rowling, (although substantially edited afterwards.)

[image]

### Other related things that quasi-count as novelizations.

**Expanded edition of original novel**

> There will also be a brand new edition of Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them in 2017, with new content by J.K. Rowling. ([Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/news/ww-publishing-cursed-child-script-book-announcement))
>
> Bloomsbury in the UK and Scholastic in the US are to build on the massive success of their ongoing Harry Potter print publishing programmes with a schedule of exciting new offerings, including: a new edition of Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them in 2017, to include new content from J.K. Rowling. ([The Blair Partnership](http://blog.theblairpartnership.com/))
>
> A brand-new edition of this essential companion to the Harry Potter stories, with a new foreword from J.K. Rowling and an irresistible new jacket by Jonny Duddle, is publishing on 9th February 2017. ([Bloomsbury](http://www.bloomsbury.com/uk/superpage/fantastic-beasts-and-where-to-find-them/))
>
> A new edition is in production, with extra material (including foreword by Newt). All my royalties will go to comicrelief, as before. ([Rowling via Twitter](https://twitter.com/jk_rowling/status/799631015098478594))
>
> A new edition of the Hogwarts Library eBook, Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them by J.K. Rowling, writing as Magizoologist Newt Scamander will be published by Pottermore on 14 March. It features a new foreword by Newt Scamander, the addition of six new beasts, new line illustrations from Tomislav Tomic that bring many of the beasts roaring to life, and a brand new cover by Olly Moss who designed the seven most recent Harry Potter eBook covers in 2015. ([Pottermore Press Release](https://www.pottermore.com/about/press-5-January-2017))

**Junior Novelizations**

> Under the agreement, Scholastic will publish children’s movie tie-in books for Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them and its sequels. ([Scholastic](http://mediaroom.scholastic.com/press-release/warner-bros-consumer-products-announces-global-publishing-partners-fantastic-beasts-an))

**Magic in North America**

This was a series of three tie-in promotional writings from Rowling that were published to Pottermore.
[*A History of Magic in North America*](https://www.pottermore.com/collection-episodic/history-of-magic-in-north-america-en), [*Ilvermorny School of Witchcraft and Wizardry*](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/ilvermorny), and [*The Magical Congress of the United States of America (MACUSA)*](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/macusa).

Comment: Junior novelisations? Score.

Comment: Oh there's nothing like multiple conflicting accounts of events to make an answer fun. Star Wars is hilarious because each film has a minimum of four different authors writing about it, all under the "official" banner..

Comment: "Other related things that quasi-count as novelizations" - JKR's collected drunken tweets

Comment: @DVK-in-exile - I personally don't get the whole "make fun of Rowling's twitter" meme.

Comment: @ibid - 50% of it is about what ANY meme is about. That is, it has little to do with meme's content and all to do with in-group/tribe membership and/or memtic stickiness. 50% of it is that she sometimes rather cavalierly amends canon, not often coherently or for that matter for the better, via twitter (which rarely implies serious thought)

Comment: @DVK-in-exile - The only tweets I've seen that really bothered me canonwise were related to Fantastic Beasts, and appeared to be more of the result of deliberate retconing she had done while writing the new FB material.

Answer (score 3):

The book **Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them** links to J. K. Rowling's fantasy book series **Harry Potter** by suggesting that it is a textbook owned by Harry Potter, mentioned in the first novel of the series, *Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone*. There are currently no public plans to novelise it, this is in very early stages. You might expect any announcements of one to come after the 3rd film has been released. You might also expect that it wouldn't be written by J. K. Rowling as she is working on other things, and it would be like writing a book two times.

The film is planned to be one of three parts written by J. K. Rowling as her screenwriting début, as well as being a producer [(see here)](http://www.businesswire.com/news/home/20151210006476/en/Announcement-Trailer-%E2%80%9CFantastic-Beasts-Find-Them%E2%80%9D-Unveiled)

Comment: Film's novelization is different from an encyclopedia which is named the same but clearly doesn't cut it as novelization, having no plot or characters :)

Comment: Downvoted because the OP explicitly excluded the current book for "obvious" reasons.

Comment: @ibid I don't see how my answer was wrong, I have looked into press releases regarding the film, it's writers and producers. There are no plans to turn this into a novelization. She is writing the screenplay for the film, not working on turning it into another book. Edited my answer to be more direct about that.

Comment: Downvote retracted.