# Has the original Fantastic Beasts book been pulled off shelves?

Tags: harry-potter, jk-rowling, fantastic-beasts

I'm not sure, but I heard that the original 'Fantastic Beasts & Where to find them' from the Hogwarts Library Set has been pulled off the shelves? That the old version will no longer be available and a different version of it is going to be released?

Is there an official source for this information if it's true?

This is the edition that I'm talking about:

[image]

Comment: Interesting question, when the movie was first announced I got confused because I already knew about this book and couldn't see how that could become a movie, then when more details about the movie came out I realised the movie has nothing to do with the book. Apparently they noticed how confusing this was going to be as well. Although it would've been better to think of a different name for the movie imo...

Comment: Was this a US edition? Because I remember the original Comic Relief version (UK) being [red](http://www.paperdroids.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/J.K.-Rowling-Writing-Harry-Potter-Inspired-Film-Series-Fantastic-Beasts-and-Where-to-Find-Them.png). Or was this another, earlier edition that I was unaware of?

Comment: Related, possible dupe: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/115272/will-there-be-a-fantastic-beasts-and-where-to-find-them-novelization

Comment: You missed an opportunity for a great Title: **"Fantastic Beasts & Where to Find Them" & Where to Find Them?**

Comment: @DavidS yes the Red edition, this green and the cream are all the same ones.

Comment: @loneboat i agree with you. You can edit the title if you want to :D .. I have my original (the green one) copy but i want to get my hands another one for a friend before the prices for the old editions shoot up ridiculously !

Comment: @ibid i was more concerned for the availability of the original 100 page book (above) (if the new book comes out) .. now that i know .. i feel the same book might come out with some additional beasts (not exactly a novel as asked in the question you linked :) )

Comment: @DavidS I got the red one in the US; it's only 42 pages.  The cream one in the image above is visibly thicker, though that could just be a thicker cover

Comment: @Izkata yes these are all probably the same book. My page count was an approximation.

Comment: @Anu7 - The accepted answer there does cover similar ground. I'm not going to VTC, but there is a relation.

Comment: @Iztaka - Interestingly, the cream one is 88 pages, but it does seem set out in order to make it as long as possible. A few sketches, pretty large gaps between the lines, etc.

Comment: I always thought the red book was about beasts and the green one about quidditch. But there are versions with opposite colors. So confusing.

Comment: @loneboat: Even better would be **Where to Find Fantastic Beasts & Where to Find Them**.

Comment: See https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/166858/4918 "How does the new edition of the Fantastic Beasts book differ from the old one?"

Answer (score 49, accepted):

[Looks like it](http://wizardsandwhatnot.com/2016/03/26/fantastic-beasts-removed-from-new-hogwarts-classics-set/):

> But with the selection of *Fantastic Beasts* to become the foundation
>   for a trilogy of films, and **Scholastic’s new deal with Warner Brothers
>   to publish it as part of the spin off works from the upcoming first
>   movie**, the new edition of Hogwarts Classics finds itself down a book.
>   Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them is no longer included. Instead
>   the Hogwarts Classics set is now just two slim volumes: Quidditch
>   Through the Ages and Tales of Beedle The Bard.

Comment: oh i wish they didn't do that.. ! thank you for your answer !

Comment: The page also continues to say that the "different version" of FB&WtFT will have a new foreword by JKR, but it doesn't mention any other changes.

Comment: oh .. will wait and see then !

Comment: Bummer... glad I have this and Quidditch Through the Ages already!

Comment: They are re-releasing them. You can pre-order now: http://www.target.com/p/hogwarts-library-hardcover-j-k-rowling/-/A-51838374?ref=tgt_adv_XS000000&AFID=google_pla_df&CPNG=PLA_Entertainment+Shopping&adgroup=SC_Entertainment&LID=700000001170770pgs&network=g&device=c&location=1016367&gclid=Cj0KEQiA5IHEBRCLr_PZvq2_6qcBEiQAL4cQ0wi0ELE7pPAdmG1_l5GWF9AkCw19HRXOPYKMyxU7pWgaArof8P8HAQ&gclsrc=aw.ds

Comment: @TylerH same here ! Its basically a more precious treasure now !

Answer (score 25):

I thought I'd leave some specific information regarding the old and new versions of *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them*, in hopes that it might be useful to some who haven't seen the original book.

You can buy the [**2009 version**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1408803011) of *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them* at Amazon (US) via third party sellers as of this writing on 19.01.17, for $4.32. There is also a version dated June 30, 2015. Also, [**a version from December 4, 2008**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0545128285) for $8.22 for the hardcover version, available directly from Amazon (US). There are a variety of versions dated in 2016.

The new *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them* is due out on March 14, 2017, and is currently [**available for pre-order**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1338132318) at Amazon (US) for $6.99 for the Kindle and $7.38 for the hardback edition. Amazon doesn't charge your account until the book ships.

I've pre-ordered [**the new Hogwarts Library**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1338132326) from Amazon (US), which will include the new *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them*, as well as *Quidditch Through the Ages* and *Tales of Beedle the Bard*, for $23.38. It's a nice looking set and is also due out on March 14, 2017.

So, yeah, there's a few links that might be helpful!

Comment: Thank You for compiling this info ! :) this is great ! I have the original Hogwarts Library Set and am planning to order one for a friend (I honestly done know if the new version will have the doodles by Harry & Ron) before the old edition is completely gone !

Answer (score 10):

### Yes

Someone asked this to J.K. Rowling on twitter, and she confirmed. You don't get more official than J.K. Rowling.

> [bruno chiaro](https://twitter.com/brunicorno/status/799629565752672256): book shops 'frustrated' as @jk_rowling 's original Fantastic Beasts book pulled from shelves for next year edition  http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/2016/11/10/book-shops-frustrated-as-jk-rowlings-original-fantastic-beasts-b/
>
> [J.K. Rowling](https://twitter.com/jk_rowling/status/799631015098478594): A new edition is in production, with extra material (including foreword by Newt). All my royalties will go to @comicrelief, as before.

<sub>(Note that Scholastic's website claims that some of the royalties will also be going to JK Rowling's charity Lumos)</sub>

Comment: The "original" book has been permanently pulled off shelves. The one releasing in March will be a different version.

Comment: Thank you for this information. Officially from Rowling herself !

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the very original version is out of print, but the new version is going to be very, very similar, just "updated."

As per Pottermore's announcement (https://www.pottermore.com/news/updated-edition-of-fantastic-beasts-library-book-will-include-new-magical-creatures) it will include six new beasts (for example the Thunderbird is not in the original) and some more on Newt Scamander to make it a closer tie-in to the movie.

Overall, the important point that I fear isn't as clear in other answers is that it is meant to be the same book, simply updated.