# How likely is a novelisation or movie of Harry Potter & the Cursed Child?

Tags: harry-potter, jk-rowling, the-cursed-child

Has J.K. Rowling ever given any clear answer on whether she might one day adapt, or allow someone to adapt, either a novelisation or TV treatment of Cursed Child? Or conversely has she ever stated definitively that she does *not* want this to happen?

Comment: The title and body of the question seem a little at odds with each other. Perhaps "What is JKR's position on adaptations of Harry Potter and the Cursed Child?" instead. It's not really possible to definitely answer if there'll *ever* be one - even if JKR is set against it now, she may change her mind in the future, or after she dies whoever inherits the rights may decide to allow one.

Comment: related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/106660/will-harry-potter-and-the-cursed-child-be-available-in-any-form-other-than-a-p/118030

Answer (score 25, accepted):

J.K. Rowling has been very clear that there are (or at least were) no plans for any adaptations.

> *Harry Potter and the Cursed Child* is a stage play, it was conceived and written as a stage play, it was always intended to be a stage play and nothing else, and there are absolutely no plans for it to become a movie, a novel, a puppet show, a cartoon, a comic book series or *Cursed Child on Ice*.
> <sub>["Cursed Child film rumours", jkrowling.com, January 2017](https://www.jkrowling.com/opinions/cursed-child-rumours/)</sub>

Comment: JKR is, of course, notoriously full of it when it comes to licensing. She also made much the same remarks about the possibility of a sequel and the possibility of allowing someone else to write it.

Comment: @Valorum - Oh yes, but these (currently) remain her only public remarks on this subject. What the future will hold is anyone's guess.

Comment: Of course, it did become a book (in screenplay format, but still a book).

Comment: @Acccumulation - This comment of Rowling's post dates the release of the screenplay, so she was presumably not considering that to be a "novel".

Comment: I've read it.  It is not a novel.

Comment: This reminds me of a quote : ["Never believe anything in politics until it has been officially denied."](https://quoteinvestigator.com/2015/08/07/believe/).

Comment: This is the same thing Lucas said about Star Wars 1-3 and 7-9 back in about 1984. Wait until there's enough money on the table...

Comment: @Valorum everyones allowed to change their mind, even JKR.